# Best SVN interface for Linux?

Tags: linux, svn

What is the best SVN GUI interface program for Linux?

I am new to Linux from being a Windows base.  For Windows I use [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and I need to know what is the Linux version.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It might not be quite what you're used to, but the command line interface is really worth learning. It's not very difficult, and the process could even help you better understand what SVN is doing. It's really quick and understanding how it works makes integrating it into your build process or other scripts a breeze.

If you'd prefer a GUI the common options are usually integration with your IDE ([Subclipse](https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse)) or [RapidSVN](https://github.com/RapidSVN/RapidSVN), though I don't have much experience with either.

Comment: another option in place of subclipse (If you are using eclipse) http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/ would be subversive.  I've used both, and they have very similar functionality.  I've not had any problems with either.  Since it's so IDE centric I didn't think it deserved its own answer.

Comment: It's *definitely* worth learning to use svn on the command line. The **svnbook** is a great guide for that: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html, especially the command reference part: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.ref

Comment: Also, IntelliJ IDEA has the best svn GUI/front-end that I'm aware of. Personally I use svn mainly through IDEA, but also on the command line. (I won't add IntelliJ IDEA as separate answer, as it is not just a TortoiseSVN-like front-end, and it's probably not worth investing in it unless you do some Java development.)

Comment: Note that SVN 1.6 allows you to abbreviate URLs on the command line, such as "svn copy ^/trunk ^/branches/hacks". This greatly reduces the amount of stuff to write when doing non-trivial stuff.

Comment: On that note, here's a post on Eclipse SVN plugins: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185486/which-eclipse-subversion-plugin-should-i-use That was back in my windows days, nowadays on ubuntu I much prefer the CLI.

Comment: Something to consider is that the command line is not accessible to everyone. The number of people who assume that because they can do it, it should be the best option for anyone is outstanding...

Comment: The CLI lacks a powerful feature: discoverability.

Answer (score 11):

[RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/) is a clone of TortoiseSVN. I love it because it integrates very well in the file navigator (Nautilus), like TortoiseSVN does in Explorer.

[image]

Comment: I installed it but didn't find a way to use it. Why do I need all those "intergrations"? What if I have nothing to integrate with? I just need a sound UI. Instead the only executable thing it installed was its "cli" version. But I'm pretty happy with svn/git CLIs.

Comment: @Onkeltem I never use its integrations (I don't use Nautilus!) but after installing I have `/usr/bin/rabbitvcs` which runs its own gui. Doesn't have all the functionality of TortoiseSVN, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 4):

I really like Tortoise SVN and would love to have something just like it for Linux. In the meantime, I've tried quite a few Linux SVN clients and the only one that seemed to have the most complete set of SVN functionality in a usable package was [Kdesvn](http://kdesvn.alwins-world.de/)

Answer (score 4):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients

Answer (score 3):

On the [SVN website](http://subversion.tigris.org/), under "Get Subversion", there's a list of Third-Party Clients. If you want to use Eclipse, there are a couple plugins there, and there's RapidSVN for Linux. And there are more, too.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/).

It has free and paid versions, but the free version should cover 90% of your needs.  It also has the advantage that it is cross-platform (java) so if you like it enough you can use it on windows too.

I [agree with jtb](https://superuser.com/questions/15371/best-svn-interface-for-linux/15375#15375) that at least some familiarity with the command line version is advantageous (then again, that's what I use on linux.)

I've become a bit disenchanted with TortoiseSVN as it seems the latest release (1.6.3) has some sort of conflict with ESET/NOD32 anti-virus which fubared a colleague's laptop (twice).

Actually, I've become disenchanted with any software that hooks into Windows Explorer too deeply - too easy for bugs to cause your system serious issues.

Answer (score 0):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). Not exactly Linux specific. But I think, if U want to compare changes at different versions, a web front end works the best.

Comment: Trac is great for viewing (my preference personally). But it's only for viewing: it's not a full client.