# svn newbie questions

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I run ubuntu and mainly use eclipse for developing my projects (java and perl).

The guys at the the office set up an SVN on our servers and I'd like to start using it.

The problem is my code is not in one big directory. Each project has its own dir, but each such dir also contains binary files, temp files etc. My question is how can I easily start using SVN - add all my code then commit easily whenever I'd like?

Also, which graphical tool you would recommend for ubuntu?

Thanks.

Comment: For tools see: http://superuser.com/questions/15371/best-svn-interface-for-linux

Comment: Could you write the question in the question field ;-) You use this field as the tags field (and also telling us that you will ask us a question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/). It's a svn-plugin for Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If I would be you, I would investigate git-svn. It is a two-way bridge that lets you interact with an SVN repo, yet it makes all cool git features available.